# ejs not parsing User object

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to learn express and i am from php background, what i am trying to achieve is set authenticated user to `res.locals` variable so authenticated user variable can be use easily in eJS.

MY app.js looks like similar to

```
initialize passport etc
///////////////////////////////////////////
//middleware to pass authuser to req locals
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.authUser = req.user;
  next();
});
```

router.js

```
router.get('/',function(req,res){
    console.log(res.locals.authUser);
    res.render('index');
});
```

index.ejs view
`<%= authUser.first_name %>`

In ejs `first_name` is not parsed but if i place this `<%= authUser %>` it renders

```
{ 
  is_admin: true,
  _id: 5d8cb3702e35aa2f5cbaabf8,
  first_name: 'ruban',
  last_name: 'shah',
  username: 'admin',
  email: 'admin@example.com',
  password: 'xxxxxx' 
}
```

which means `authUser` is Object but it does not print `authUser.first_name` is ejs

but strange thing is it renders authUser.username

Comment: Do _any_ properties work?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is, when you are adding user to sesison after user login, you are not adding the user object rather you are adding JSON String.